# Run an aspx page and have dlls in layouts folder instead of GAC - sharepoint

Tags: 2007, assembly-references, hosting

I have created an asp.net project . i want to run that project in SharePoint (2007) site. unfortunately i have no rights to deploy WSP files in sharepoint server. it is a share hosting. i can access only layouts folder. is it possible to place my DLLs in layouts folder and run my asp page. Anybody faced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible.  You will need to place your assemblies in either the bin folder or the GAC in order to execute them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So can't we install any .wsp files in shared hosting? what is the way if i have bought a shared hosting server and have to install an .wsp file.

Comment: You would need to talk to your host administrator about that.  .wsp files will deploy assemblies to the GAC or bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Caution: it's a very bad pratice** but just for testing purpose if you could drag and drop your Assembly to C:\Windows\Assembly on the Server and aspx pages in layouts. Then perform the IISReset /noforce afterwards and try testing the Application page afterwards.

Comment: he says he cant instal WSPs.. do you think he will have access to this folder?

Comment: since he can access the layouts folder wondering he might also sneak into c:\windows\assembly ;)

Comment: no... its shared hosting and most problably he will be accessing layouts folder through a web interface :)

Comment: oh it's gonna be a real struggle ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start looking for a new Hosting provider.

Giving you access to the layouts folder is definitly not good practise. This will allow you to break as much as if you had access to install WSPs, but without allowing you to do the right thing.